# Use a string in another class depending on the option chosen by user

Tags: java, android

I have a menu at the beginning of my application which allows the user to choose a specific type of diet, I want to save this as a string to use in another class which finds nearby restaurants,cafes,etc.

For example, if the user chooses the "Vegan" card, then I want to be able to use "Vegan" in other classes, but if it's "Kosher" I want to use the string "kosher" in other classes.

I tried creating a `DietChoice` class to set/get the diet but that doesn't work because I can't create a `HomeMenu` object in my `MapsActivity` class.

How can I make it so that when the user clicks the Vegan card, I can make it so that I can use a string "Vegan" in my `MapsActivity` class?

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.View;

public class HomeMenu extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private CardView veganMenu,halalMenu,vegeterianMenu,kosherMenu;
private DietChoice diet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_menu);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);



}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Home.class)
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.vegan_menu:
            intent.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", "vegan");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.vegetarian_menu:
            intent.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", "vegetarian");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.halal_menu:
            intent.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", "halal");
            startActivity(intent);      
            break;
        case R.id.kosher_menu:
            intent.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", "kosher");
            startActivity(intent);      
            break;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use shared preferences? https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello just putExtra with intent and extract it later on in your next Activity.No need of any Pojo.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.View;

public class HomeMenu extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private CardView veganMenu,halalMenu,vegeterianMenu,kosherMenu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_menu);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    veganMenu = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.vegan_menu);
    halalMenu = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.vegetarian_menu);
    vegeterianMenu = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.halal_menu);
    kosherMenu = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.kosher_menu);

    veganMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
    halalMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
    vegeterianMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
    kosherMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Home.class)
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.vegan_menu:
            intent.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", "vegan");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.vegetarian_menu:
            intent.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", "vegetarian");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.halal_menu:
            intent.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", "halal");
            startActivity(intent);      
            break;
        case R.id.kosher_menu:
            intent.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", "kosher");
            startActivity(intent);      
            break;
    }
}
}
```

To Retrive the String in Home activity use below Code

```
String newString;
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        newString= null;
    } else {
        newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
    }
} else {
    newString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_I_NEED");
}
```

Comment: PutExtra is to send data with intent it will work for sure.

Comment: in putExtra the second argument should it be a variable or a string?

Comment: Yes put string or primitive data type or any parcelable object